# JSON Web service to HTML dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a Web service which returns a **JSON** file, and I'm required to show the data in an HTML **dropdown** (select). How can I do this with jQuery or any other method?

Comment: Check out this link: http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.getJSON(
    "/path/to/service",
    function(data) {

        var $s = $('.your_select_element').empty();

        // the actual contents of this loop will be
        // specific to the data
        for (var k in data) {
            $('<option></option>')
                .val(data[k].value)
                .text(data[k].text)
                .appendTo($s);
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "http://pathto.html",
    dataType: JSON,
    success: function(data){
        $(data).each(function(){
            $("select").append();//Append what you want.
        });
    }
```

Comment: jimbojw version is correct, I just grabbed the closet code i had that would get it done.